# regular expressions programming

Tags: regex

> Write a regular expression that matches a string that has the word PHP in it. It must be PHP on its own (The string “See PHP.NET” does not match, but the string “PHP is a scripting language” does match!)

The answer that i have is not giving me the result im supposed to have for this question:

```
^.PHP/g
```

Comment: Your regex asserts start-of-line followed by any single character, then `PHP/g` literally. I don't think that's what you intend.

Comment: What do you mean by _It must be PHP on its own_ ?

Comment: What is the quoted text from? Should `See PHP.NET` be matched? Your regex is looking at the start of the the string, a non new line character, then PHP.

Comment: [And it appears you have asked same thing on from different account.](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Wy4mDnF8uEsJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/43833584/regular-expressions-regex+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
(?<=^|\s)PHP(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: If only you got a grade for doing someone else's homework... or depriving the student of doing their own learning.

Comment: @DaveNewton that's not my business if student don't want to learn by themself

Comment: I guess we have a different ethos regarding other peoples' work ¯\(°_o)/¯